# How to include a line containing an error in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am putting together a small tutorial using R Markdown. I want to include the following:

This is how we create a vector in R:

`{r}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x`

We need to use the c() operator to do this; if we don't we get an error as shown below:

`{r}
x <- (1,2,3,4,5)`

I want to show the error message that R would normally give if I tried to create a vector without the c(), namely

"Error: unexpected ',' in "x <- (1,"

However, when I knit the markdown it stops at the line containing the error. So, how do I deliberately include a line with a mistake in it, in order to demonstrate the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

````
```{r, error = TRUE}
x <- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```
````

An upgrade to `knitr` changed the default behavior of the `error` option from `TRUE` to `FALSE`.  You'll either need to set `error = TRUE` in each chunk where you want it or use `opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)` at the start of your script.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a change in `knitr`, or the fact that RStudio uses `rmarkdown::render` at the top level, which changes the defaults ... ?

Comment: You're correct.  Thanks for clarifying.  (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html)

Comment: Thanks. However, having tried each option you suggest, I still end up with the same error:
Quitting from lines 63-64 (M1.2_DataInR.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:1:8: unexpected ','
1: x <- (1, ^Calls: <Anonymous> ... evaluate -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse
Execution halted. I also tried the following code at the top of my Rmd script: ```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error=TRUE)``` as suggested in the migration guide linked above, but with the same result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Benjamin's answer will work. Doesn't work for me at least - because the error is a syntax error.

I have two imperfect solutions to this problem. You can 'hack' something that looks right by not evaluating the code with the syntax error, then having a chunk underneath which is evaluated and just shows the error message.

````
```{r, eval = FALSE}
x <- (1,2,3,4,5)
```
```{r, echo = FALSE}
cat("Error: unexpected \',\' in \'try(x <- (1,\'")
```
````

Or you can run the code in a different engine. However, it also gives a message saying execution halted that I can't work out how to remove.

````
```{r, engine='Rscript', error=TRUE}
x <- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```
````

Comment: Your first solution works like a charm, thanks much!!

Comment: I've edited the code again - that should give an even better result. The previous version was giving a different error message from what you would really see.

Comment: Yes I noticed that - however since I am pasting in the error message verbatim anyway, I decided not to put it in a chunk at all, and just showed it as ordinary text. Thanks.